# Building an array, works but taking a count afterwards doesn't?

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have 2 arrays that contain data I'm combining into a 3rd. The array displays correctly but when I try to run a count() on it, it returns 0 which makes no sense.

```
foreach ($xmlm->support_team as $support_team){
   $arr_team['Teams'][(string)$support_team->name]['Representatives'] = array(0);
   $members = $support_team->members;
   foreach ($members->representative as $representative){
        $teamMemberID = $representative->attributes();
        $teamMemberName = $representative->display_name;
        foreach ($xmlr->rep as $rep){
            $repID = $rep->attributes();
            If (strcmp($repID, $teamMemberID) == 0){
                $repcountperteam = $repcountperteam + 1;
                $arr_team['Teams'][(string)$support_team->name]['Representatives'][0] = $repcountperteam;
                $repName = $rep->public_display_name;
                $sessionCount = $rep->support_session_count + $rep->presentation_count;
                $repDirectLink = $rep->direct_link->a['href'];
                $arr_team['Teams'][(string)$support_team->name]['Representatives'][] = 
                  "Direct Chat With <a href=" 
                  . $repDirectLink . "&customer_name=" 
                  . $samname . "&c2cjs=1 target=\"_blank\">" 
                  . $repName . "</a> (currently in " 
                  . $sessionCount . " sessions)<br />";
            }
        }
    }
    $repcountperteam = 0;
}
```

If I try to do a

```
print_r(count($arr_team->teams));
```

or an

```
echo count($arr_team->teams);
```

it returns 0?

When I display the array it looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [Teams] => Array
        (
            [Clinical Apps] => Array
                (
                    [Representatives] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => Direct Chat With servicea (currently in 0 sessions)

                        )

                )

            [Pass-Thru] => Array
                (
                    [Representatives] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                        )

                )

            [Support] => Array
                (
                    [Representatives] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 14
                            [1] => Direct Chat With Snair, Adam (currently in 1 sessions)

                            [2] => Direct Chat With Ponce, Agustin (currently in 0 sessions)

                            [3] => Direct Chat With Fink, Kevin (currently in 1 sessions)

                            [4] => Direct Chat With D'Sousa, Roshni (currently in 1 sessions)

                            [5] => Direct Chat With Kazmierczak, Jon (currently in 0 sessions)

                            [6] => Direct Chat With Sanchez, Nick (currently in 1 sessions)

                            [7] => Direct Chat With Quinto, Joseph (currently in 0 sessions)

                            [8] => Direct Chat With Peralta, Oswaldo (currently in 1 sessions)

                            [9] => Direct Chat With Deonarain, Jason (currently in 1 sessions)

                            [10] => Direct Chat With Lysikatos, Chris (currently in 1 sessions)

                            [11] => Direct Chat With Ford, Andre (currently in 0 sessions)

                            [12] => Direct Chat With Lau, Mark (currently in 0 sessions)

                            [13] => Direct Chat With Ferrigno, Chris (currently in 0 sessions)

                            [14] => Direct Chat With Mendez, Oscar (currently in 0 sessions)

                        )

                )

        )

)
1
```

Comment: `$arr_team->teams` is expecting an object, you have an array. Try `echo count( $arr_team['Teams']);`.

Comment: That worked, thank you. However now I'm stuck pulling each piece of representative data PER team. I know how to step through a nested SimpleXML Object, but the array I'm getting tripped up with.